# Javascript regex created from string - why it does not work?

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is:

```
...
abc {
   color: red;
   border-color: black;
}
...
```

I would like to match (replace) everything between curly braces. I managed to write working regexp like this:

```
/\{[.\s\w:;-]*\}/ig
```

But I need to create regexp from string and it does not work:

```
new RegExp("{[.\s\w:;-]*}","ig"); // does not work
```

Everything is on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ru18Lj9/

Comment: Try printing out the regexp after you've created it. It should be quite clear what is going on.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse CSS with regexps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this updated fiddle.

You have to escape the slashes . tats it

```
new RegExp("{[.\\s\\w:;-]*}","ig");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/khaleel/3ru18Lj9/2/

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
var re = new RegExp("\\{[\\S\\s]*\\}", "g");
```

to match newlines as well in JS.

- You must use `\\` (double escaping) while constructing `RegExp` object.
- Since JS doesn't have `s` (DOTALL) flag use `[\S\s]` to match all characters including newlines.

**PS:** However remember that it won't handle nested braces.

Answer (score 2):

`\s` in a regexp means something special but `\s` in a string is the same as just `s`.

You need to escape the `\`, so that the regular expression parser sees it.

```
new RegExp("\\{[.\\s\\w:;-]*\\}","ig");
```